# Suppose $l$ satisfies $l'(t)=-1+f(t)l(t)$, where $f$ is monotone increasing with asymptote $d$. For which initial conditions of $l$ is $l$ decreasing?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $l$ satisfies differential equation $l'(t)=-1+f(t)l(t)$. Here $f$ is a monotone increasing function towards a limit $d$. Determine a constraint on the initial condition of $l$ such that $l$ is monotone decreasing.

When I solve this differential equation by adding the homogeneous and a particular solution, I find $l(t)=e^{F(t)}\left(c-\int_{0}^{t}e^{-F(\tau)}d\tau\right)$, for a constant $c$. Here $F$ is a primitive of $f$, which is a convex function since $f$ is monotone increasing. If I choose $F$ such that it satisfies $F(0)=0$, I find that $l(0)=c$.

I have the feeling there is a certain upper bound for $c$ such that $l$ is monotone decreasing. But I don't know how to proceed..
Any help is very much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

L is decreasing, right ? So its derivative $\frac{dl}{dt}$ is negative so $f(t)\cdot l(t) -1 < 0 \leftrightarrow f(t)\cdot l(t) < 1 \leftrightarrow l(t) < \frac{1}{f(t)}$ to garentee that l will allways be monotone decreasing we can let $l(t)$ be less that the least value of $\frac{1}{f(t)}$ this is true because if we pick any value of f less that d then $\frac{1}{f} > \frac{1}{d} > l(t) $ and $l(t)$ will be then decreasing, we can set $\frac{1}{d} $ as an upper bound of $l(t)$ to garentee its monote decrease for example let $l(0) = 0$

Comment: Alright, thank you. I understand if $l(0)<\frac{1}{d}$, then $l$ will be decreasing for all $t>0$. But is that the lowest upper bound? How do I prove that? I would like to derive a restriction of $l(0)$ following from: 'Given that $l$ is decreasing, then $l(0)<c_1$ ', where $c_1$ is the constant we have to determine. Thank you again!

Comment: I've edit the answer, feel free to check it !